# casting error when casting a list of object to a dictionary of enum as key and list of objects as value

Tags: c#, dictionary, casting

I have enum/classes as follows

```
public enum TestType
{
    Automatic,
    Manual,
    SemiManual,
    SemiAutomatic
}

public class TestCase
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

}

public class TestData
{
    public TestType TestType { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Its used as follows

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<TestData> data = new List<TestData>()
    {
        new TestData(){ TestType = TestType.Automatic, Id = 21 },
        new TestData(){ TestType = TestType.SemiAutomatic, Id = 34 },
        new TestData(){ TestType = TestType.SemiManual, Id = 13 },
        new TestData(){ TestType = TestType.Manual, Id = 14 },
        new TestData(){ TestType = TestType.Automatic, Id = 45 },
        new TestData(){ TestType = TestType.Automatic, Id = 56 }
    };


}
```

I need to convert this list into a `Dictionary<TestType, List<TestCase>>`. For that I have code as follows.

```
Dictionary<TestType, List<TestCase>> dataAsDictionary =
                        data.GroupBy(x => x.TestType)
                        .ToDictionary(k => k.Key, v => v.Select( f=> 
                                new TestCase() { Id = f.Id }));
```

> Error CS0029  Cannot implicitly convert type
>   '`System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<ConsoleApp2.TestType,
>   System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<ConsoleApp2.TestCase>>`' to
>   '`System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<ConsoleApp2.TestType,
>   System.Collections.Generic.List<ConsoleApp2.TestCase>>`'  ConsoleApp2

How can I resolve this error? I try various combinations of casting but that doesn't seem to help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `ToList` call:

```
Dictionary<TestType, List<TestCase>> dataAsDictionary =
                        data.GroupBy(x => x.TestType)
                        .ToDictionary(k => k.Key, v => v.Select( f=> 
                                new TestCase() { Id = f.Id }).ToList());
```

It's needed because `Select` returns `IEnumerable<T>` and not `List<T>`.

Answer (score 2):

You get this error because `Select()` returns `IEnumerable<T>`, while your `Dictionary` wants values of type `List<T>`.

Add a call of `ToList()` to fix this problem:

```
Dictionary<TestType,List<TestCase>> dataAsDictionary = data
    .GroupBy(x => x.TestType)
    .ToDictionary(
        k => k.Key
    ,   v => v.Select( f=> new TestCase() { Id = f.Id }).ToList()
    ); //                                               ^^^^^^^^^
```